# Batch or Chain for jobs inside jobs

Tags: laravel, jobs, laravel-8

I have job A which downloads xml and then calls other job B which will create data on database. This job B will be called in loop and can be more than 10.000 items. First tried to use chain method but problem is that, if someone will call queue in wrong sequence it will not work. Then tried to use batch from new Laravel 8. Collecting all jobs (more than 10000) to one batch can cause out of memory exception. Other problem is calling job C at the end. This job will update some credentials. Thats why job A and B must be runned successfully. May be there is any good idea for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel's job batching feature allows you to easily execute a batch of jobs and then perform some action when the batch of jobs has completed executing.

If you have an out-of-memory problem with Jobs Batching you are doing things wrong. Since the queues are executed one by one if you have it configured that way there should be no problems, even if they are more than 100k records. So, make sure you glue one Job for each item, and execute the action, you won't have problems with this.

Then, you could do something like this.

```
$chain = [
    new ProcessPodcast(Podcast::find(1)),
    new ProcessPodcast(Podcast::find(2)),
    new ProcessPodcast(Podcast::find(3)),
    new ProcessPodcast(Podcast::find(4)),
    new ProcessPodcast(Podcast::find(5)),
    ...
    // And so on for all your items.
    // This should be generated by a foreach with all his items.
];

Bus::batch($chain)->then(function (Batch $batch) {
    // All jobs completed successfully...
    // Uupdate some credentials...
})->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
    // First batch job failure detected...
})->finally(function (Batch $batch) {
    // The batch has finished executing...
})->dispatch();
```

Comment: Is it a problem to call a new, different, cleanup job in the `then` method?

Comment: In theory there should be no problem, but the most logical thing to do would be to chain these in the same chain.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm talking about a final job that requires data to be set in jobs during the initial batch.